# Values in multiple select box disappear when selected

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, multiple-select

So I have a 2 multiple select box (one for the floor and one for the room). The values in the Room depends on the Floor. If you choose Floor: 001 all the values in the Room will start on 1 and if you choose Floor: 002 all the values in the Room will start in 2, and so on. But when I select the values in the Room all of the values will disappear, here's my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(

        function()
        {
              var selectArr = []; 
              $("select").change(function(){
                  var arr = $(this).val()
                   selectArr.push(arr);
                   console.log(arr)
                   populateRooms();
                   clearArray();
                });


              function clearArray() {
                  return selectArr = []
                }     

        function populateRooms() {
        $.ajax({

                type: "GET",
                url: "/hms/shifts/" + selectArr,
                success: function (response) {
                 $('#_rooms_id').empty();
                    var myObject = eval('(' + response + ')');
                    for (i in myObject)
                    {
                        $('#_rooms_id').append(
                                $('<option></option>', 
                                { 
                                    value: myObject[i]["id"],
                                    text: myObject[i]["roomNumber"]
                                }
                                )
                             );
                    }

                },
               error: function (e){
                   alert("Error" + e)
               }
           });
        }

        });

  </script>
```

I think it's because of the `.empty()` but if I remove that all of the values in room will show, there will be no filter. I hope someone can help me. Newbie here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should add the event to populate rooms-select only in the floor-select

This code add the onChange event to ALL dropdowns in your code:

```
 $("select").change(function(){
              var arr = $(this).val()
               selectArr.push(arr);
               console.log(arr)
               populateRooms();
               clearArray();
            });
```

Change to this:

```
$("#floors-dropdownId").change(function(){
              var arr = $(this).val()
               selectArr.push(arr);
               console.log(arr)
               populateRooms();
               clearArray();
            });
```

Comment: It worked Sir! Thank you. :) But when I don't select anything on the Floor the values of the Room is still being shown, it should not it should be empty. Why is that? I hope you can help me Sir.

Answer (score 1):

You have applied generic 'change' event on all select which causes it to clear.

```
//you have issue here , $(select) means all selects in your current DOM!      

$("select").change(function(){
              var arr = $(this).val()
               selectArr.push(arr);
               console.log(arr)
               populateRooms();
               clearArray();
            });
```

Chang to ,

```
// Apply change on specific instead
$("select#floorId").change(function(){
              var arr = $(this).val()
               selectArr.push(arr);
               console.log(arr)
               populateRooms();
               clearArray();
            });
```

Comment: It worked Sir! Thank you. :) But when I don't select anything on the Floor the values of the Room is still being shown, it should not it should be empty. Why is that? I hope you can help me Sir.

Comment: @KendallH.yes you should add a validation in the onCHange method, and check if the value of the floor=="" (empty) then clean the rooms dropdown

Comment: @KendallH. you have 3 values in floor so any one is by default selected. In this case another option like '--select--'  and on selection of this clear all rooms

Comment: @TechBreak can you show me how to do that Sir? Sorry. I'm really new with javascript. Be patient with me. Thank you.

Comment: @KendallH. in your floor select add one more option <option value="0" selected>--select--</option>

Comment: @TechBreak this is my new script with the floor id: http://pastie.org/private/ottpabn1q5ihcey1q9n27a where should I put the option Sir? I'm quite confuse.

Comment: @TechBreak I tried this Sir: http://pastie.org/10968286 but still getting the same result.

Comment: @KendallH. add this before for loop in your code.$('#_rooms_id').append(
$('<option value="0"></option>')

Comment: @TechBreak before `for (i in myObject)` line Sir?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128819/discussion-between-kendall-h-and-techbreak).